# Dependent picklist in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to create a dependent picklist in LWC and it is somehow not working. I have a controlling picklist called Event Types. The values for this picklist are fetched from a picklist field present on custom object Event. When a user changes the value in this picklist, in the onchange method, I am calling an Apex class which fetches the value for the dependent picklist. The values are getting returned as expected from Apex, then I am creating the array of objects for the dependent picklist, but the updated values are not getting displayed in the dependent picklist. Can anyone please let me know what's the problem with my code. Thanks.

```
<template>
<lightning-layout class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
    <lightning-layout-item size="4" padding="around-small" class="slds-box">
        <template if:true={eventTypes.data}>
            <lightning-combobox
              name="eventType"
              label="Choose Event Type"
              value={selectedEventType}
              placeholder="Select Event Type"
              options={eventTypes.data.values}
              onchange={handleEventTypeChange}
            ></lightning-combobox>
          </template>
          <lightning-combobox
              name="objects2"
              label="Choose Object"
              value={selectedObject}
              placeholder="Choose Object"
              options={objects}
            ></lightning-combobox>
    </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
```

JS Controller

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from "lwc";
import { getPicklistValues } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
import EVENT_TYPE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Event__c.Event_Type__c";
import { getObjectInfo } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
import EVENT_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Event__c";
import getSupportedObjects from "@salesforce/apex/PicklistController.getSupportedObjects";

export default class EventList extends LightningElement {
  @track selectedEventType;
  @track selectedObject;
  @track objects = [];
  @track error;

  @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: EVENT_OBJECT })
  objectInfo;

  @wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
    fieldApiName: EVENT_TYPE_FIELD
  })
  eventTypes;

  handleEventTypeChange(event) {
    console.log("*****objects before push:", JSON.stringify(this.objects));
    this.objects = [];
    this.selectedEventType = event.detail.value;
    getSupportedObjects({ eventType: this.selectedEventType })
      .then(result => {
        result.forEach(element =>
          this.objects.push({
            label: element.Object__c,
            value: element.Object__c
          })
        );
        console.log("*****objects after push:", JSON.stringify(this.objects));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
      });
  }
}
```

The output of console log:

*****objects before push: []
*****objects after push: [{"label":"Account","value":"Account"}]

Apex Class:

```
public class PicklistController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Configuration__c> getSupportedObjects(String eventType){
        return [SELECT Object__c FROM Configuration__c WHERE Event_Type__c=: eventType];
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason the UI is not recognising that objects has been updated. In your `then` block instead on directly adding to `this.objects`, add to a temporary array. Then you can assign the temporary array to `this.objects`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

The object should be `Event__c`.

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Event__c">
// Your html
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

By default when using **record edit form** dependent pick-list values will be updated for you, this will be the case if both fields are within your HTML.

Comment: Carlos, I doubt this would work as its not actually a dependent picklist but a lookup shown as picklist values.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, yes, this is only going to work if we talk about dependent lists.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `forEach` in js does not implicitly capture `this`, you have to pass it like so:

```
Array.forEach(x => {}, this);
```

However, and most likely, this is a known limitation where even with `@track` array elements are not observed.
Use spread operator, changing this code here:

```
let newObjects = [];
getSupportedObjects({ eventType: this.selectedEventType })
      .then(result => {
        result.forEach(element =>
          newObjects.push({
            label: element.Object__c,
            value: element.Object__c
          })
        });
        this.objects = [...newObjects];
        console.log("*****objects after push:", JSON.stringify(this.objects));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
      });
```